# Any Open Source Extensions to ESRI JSAPI?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoext, dojo

I'm looking for some functionality beyond what ESRI already provides in the JSAPI.  For example, the ability to display the LOD in a tooltip on the zoom control.  It seems like there should be a dojo+jsapi answer to openlayers+geoext but I have not found it.

Can anyone point me to Any Open Source Extensions to ESRI JSAPI?

Comment: Why not look at using OpenLayers or Leaflet? What is keeping you stuck on the JSAPI?

Comment: I work with OpenLayers + Dojo as well but this isn't really an answer.  What would be great is a toolkit which extends both OL and JSAPI using a common interface...but that's another topic.  Presently I'm looking for pre-build solutions to further enhance what ESRI + dojo already provide.  _ is to JSAPI+Dojo as geoext is to OL+ExtJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that the JSAPI already provides equivalent functionality to what's in GeoExt. All of the additional widgets provided by dojo are just a require statement away. It's up to you how you use them.

Here's an example of a JSAPI site that has always struck me as having a "GeoExt feel":  http://uplan.utah.gov/

For your specific case of a tooltip on the zoom control, I know I've seen this on some sites in the past that do this but I'm not able to quickly find one. CrimeMapping.com kind of does this:  http://www.crimemapping.com/map.aspx

And we have a sample showing how to change the zoom slider ticks:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/mapconfig/mapconfig_customlabels.html

But I don't think that's what you're asking. How's this look:  http://jsfiddle.net/V2E8b/

Comment: These don't address the specific example I mentioned, which is an equal to http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/zoomslider.html nor is it any better than saying ExtJS already exists so why bother with GeoExt?  There would be value in a community built extension to JSAPI...but perhaps nothing like that yet exists.  Regarding *your* solution...It's close but was looking for a tooltip on the slider itself.  I believe the solution at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2E8b/1/) is better than the tooltip I was looking for because it puts the zoom info right on the slider.

Comment: I extended your solution to place the tooltip on the handle which does now address the need of the example I mentioned in the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/V2E8b/2/

But as far as I know there's no place for me to capture and share this progress with fellow JSAPI developers.

Comment: @user2023 I'm not that familiar with GeoExt so I didn't know you were talking about a specific sample. In the future, please link to what you're talking about. Regarding sharing, arcgis.com has has a code gallery:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisonline/help/index.html#//010q0000002m000000 There's also github...